# isLenient function to check if date is valid

Tags: java

I am looking to check if the date I set is valid or not. This is how I have attempted to do it:

```
public boolean validDate() {
    return calendar.isLenient();
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
Date date = new Date(36, 04, 2014);
System.out.println("Day = " + date.getDay());
System.out.println("Month = " + date.getMonth());
System.out.println("Year = " + date.getYear());
System.out.println("Is valid? = " + date.validDate());
System.out.println("Last day? = " + date.LastDayOfMonth(02));
```

And it returns this -

```
Day = 36
Month = 4
Year = 2014
Is valid? = true
Last day? = false
```

My question is why does it say it is valid even though it is not. Also how would I check to see if it is a false date or not?

Comment: check what is leninent on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606387/what-is-the-use-of-lenient
and check for valid date in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528047/checking-the-validity-of-a-date

Comment: `isLenient` doesn't tell you whether a date is valid.  Furthermore, it looks like you're using your own `Date` class, and that you've defined a `calendar` field, and have not let us in on the secret of how `calendar` is set up.  We will need more information.

Comment: @ajb this is my data class. if you find anything wrong or bad just tell me please as I am still new and will really appreciate advice. http://pastebin.com/7GSK7ARQ

Answer (score 1):

A `Calendar` can be either in "lenient" or "non-lenient" mode.  If it's in lenient mode, it can accept invalid values (like day=36) and interpret them somehow; if it's in non-lenient mode and you try to set invalid values, an exception will be thrown (but not necessarily right away; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436524/checking-if-the-date-is-valid-using-calendar).

`isLenient` will tell you whether the `Calendar` is in lenient or non-lenient *mode*, but it tells you nothing about whether the data is valid.

To test whether the values are valid, you can try another `Calendar` in non-lenient mode.  Your class has `day`, `month`, and `year` fields, so you can try something like:

```
public boolean validDate() {
    try {
        Calendar tempCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        tempCal.setLenient(false);
        tempCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        tempCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        tempCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        tempCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            // throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if any field is invalid; we don't care about the
            // method result
        return true;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't affect your `calendar` field which may still be in lenient mode.

**EDIT:** Now tested.  The javadoc says `get()` throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if any data is invalid, but I believe this may be an error in the javadoc.  I'll try to report this to Oracle.

Comment: It worked however I now get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException instead of returning false.

Comment: @user3456349 I've fixed this, and I've had a chance to test it.  My answer was based on the javadoc, but the javadoc apparently has a mistake.